# Resolving an amibguous ValueError in Flask with jquery POST data:

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a simple app in Flask that pulls in data from the pokemon.csv often used on Kaggle.com for data visualizations.  There are several parts to this and I have most of them working, but am running into an odd problem in getting my final dataframe.  Here's the setup:

```
app.py
   |
   V
pokemon.html
   |
   V
_poke-info.html
```

app.py: this is a file with a route to a page ('pokemon') that has a dynamically-generated dropdown list that pulls in all the Pokemon types from the 'Type 1' column, as well as their value counts.  This works well (after converting the value_counts to a dict()).  When a user changes a selection in the list in pokemon.html, my goal is to pull in the data associated with that pokemon Type 1 type.  To do this, app.py checks for POST data to a component file ("_poke-info.html") that is included after the list using a jinja `{% include "_poke-info" %}` command.  The updated info should then be displayed in the included html below the original dropdown in pokemon.html (by reloading the updated _poke-info.html into a `<div id="poke-info">`).  I can make the round trip from the original page, to the .csv and back work, displaying updated information in the included _poke-info.html file.

The one problem I can't resolve is that I keep getting an error when I try to get a slice of the dataframe in app.py. In app.py, I have the following to handle the POST request:

```
@app.route("/poke-info", methods=["POST"])
def poke_info():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        type = request.form['chosen_pokemon']
        pk = pd.read_csv('static/data/pokemon-plotting.csv')
        data = pk.loc[pk['Type 1']==type]
        return render_template("components/_poke-info.html", chosen_pokemon = data)
    return ''
```

The problem arises when I try to filter the dataframe.  I keep getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Curiously, when I run that same code in a Jupyter notebook (`data = pk.loc[pk['Type 1']==type]`) I get precisely the dataframe slice I'm looking for.  I've searched online and everything regarding this error message seems to revolve around checking for multiple conditions on Booleans and using '&' and '|' instead of "and" or "or". The other suggestion has been to put the condition in parentheses or to use .loc. I've tried both of those, but keep getting the same error. I've tried renaming my variables so that they are not scoped to the same namespace as any other variables I might've created in any other functions.  But I keep getting this ambiguous ValueError.

How can I resolve this and get a slice of the dataframe? It seems to work in Jupyter, so it's unclear to me why this would be ambiguous.

Comment: UPDATE_1: I thought I might try to filter the data using .query() instead.  So I typed: ```data = pk.query(f'`Type 1`=="{type}"')```.  This works to get the same data in pandas using Jupyter notebook.  However, It ended up giving me the same error when I tried to get this data in my flask app.  It seems there is a problem filtering the dataframe in flask.

Answer (score 0):

So, a friend pointed out that the problem is not with pandas, but with how jinja handles the "truthiness" of a dataframe. The problem was with the following code in the template that was intended to render the data:

```
{% if chosen_pokemon %}
    {{chosen_pokemon | safe}}
{% else %}
    <h4>No information to show</h4>
{% endif %}
```

Because chosen_pokemon was a dataframe, jinja could not evaluate whether or not it was True.  I looked up how to check the existence of a variable in jinja and found that "is defined" accomplishes this.  So, the corrected code is:

```
{% if chosen_pokemon is defined %}
    {{chosen_pokemon | safe}}
{% else %}
    <h4>No information to show</h4>
{% endif %}
```

Once I put this in place, everything rendered as expected.

@davidism, I noticed that you removed the "flask" tag from this question.  Inasmuch as the problem was caused by the flask templating engine (via jinja), can you please add that tag back to the question?  Thanks!